# Modelling a moving window with a shift( ) function in python problem

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sum, rolling-computation

Problem: Lets suppose that we supply robots to a factory. Each of these robots is programmed to switch into the work mode after 3 days (e.g. if it arrives on day 1, it starts working on day 3), and then they work for 5 days. after that, the battery runs out and they stop working. The number of robots supplied each day varies.
The following code is the supplies for the first 15 days like so:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'date': ['01','02', '03', '04', '05','06', \
           '07','08','09','10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15'],
  'value': [10,20,20,30,20,10,30,20,10,20,30,40,20,20,20]
})

df.set_index('date',inplace=True)
df
```

Let's now estimate the number of working robots on each of these days like so ( we move two days back and sum up only the numbers within the past 5 days):

```
04  10
05  20+10 = 30
06  20+20 = 40 
07  30+20 = 50
08  20+30 = 50
09  10+20 = 30
10  30+10 = 40
11  20+30 = 50
12  10+20 = 30
13  20+10 = 30
14  30+20 = 50 
15  40+30 = 70
```

Is it possible to model this in python? I have tried this - not quite but close.

```
df_p = (((df.rolling(2)).sum())).shift(5).rolling(1).mean().shift(-3)
```

p.s. if you dont think its complicated enough then I also need to include the last 7-day average for each of these numbers for my real problem.

Comment: Just fyi the [tag:shift] is for "Questions related to the usage of the right and/or left shift key on the keyboard." and does not apply for this purpose.

Comment: hi Corralien. I accepted it. this problem is very much related to that one. however, I cant use cumsum() here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) forward first the window (5) less the rolling window length (2) and taking [`rolling sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.sum.html) with min periods set to `1`:

```
shift_window = 5
rolling_window = 2
df['new_col'] = (
    df['value'].shift(shift_window - rolling_window)
        .rolling(rolling_window, min_periods=1).sum()
)
```

Or with hard coded values:

```
df['new_col'] = df['value'].shift(3).rolling(2, min_periods=1).sum()
```

`df`:

```
      value  new_col
date                
01       10      NaN
02       20      NaN
03       20      NaN
04       30     10.0
05       20     30.0
06       10     40.0
07       30     50.0
08       20     50.0
09       10     30.0
10       20     40.0
11       30     50.0
12       40     30.0
13       20     30.0
14       20     50.0
15       20     70.0
```

Comment: Interesting. thank you. I'll see if I get more responses and accept the answer tomorrow.

Comment: Let me know if it works as expected. It seems it works for this example but I don’t know how durable the logic is.